# USB composite device - Xinput and CDC

Tags: usb, microcontroller, xinput

I'm trying to emulate an Xinput gamepad on a microcontroller (nRF52).
I have configured all the necessary USB descriptors, interfaces and endpoints, and it works. The device is enumerated on Windows as an Xbox 360 controller, I can send gamepad reports to the PC, they are correctly detected, and everything is okay so far.

Now I'm trying to make this device a composite USB device, by adding CDC ACM descriptors and functionality. When I use the Microsoft VID (0x045E) and PID (0x028E), the COM port is not enumerated on Windows, I can't use the CDC interface to communicate.
If I use a different VID or PID, the Xinput is not working anymore.

I'm suspecting that these are the Windows drivers, they are ignoring Xinput USB devices that do not use the correct VID and PID.

The goal is to find a way to send some "control" data from the PC to the microcontroller over the USB, ideally via some kind of web-utility.

The questions are:

1. Is it possible to use Microsoft VID and PID and have the COM port on
   the device without creating a new Windows driver?
2. Is it possible to not use Microsoft VID and PID and still have the
   Xinput functionality?

Anny suggestion is welcome.

Thanks
Best regards
Emir

Comment: Did you consider to insert a (virtual) USB hub? This way each of both devices can have their own VID/PID. -- I found in many painful years that Windows is notoriously lacking standard conformity. For example, I would expect acceptance of a generic CDC/ACM independent of VID/PID ... but as you see, it does not. -- Anyway, did you try to provide an own INF file?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.
I'm not familiar with such concept, virtual USB hub. How does that work? Any references to this?
Also, no, I did not try with INF file. I'm not really familiar with that either.

Comment: Answers to your additional questions in the comments do not fit well on this site. I'm afraid that you will need to do your research and learn a lot. Good luck!